# What do you call the air that rushes into your car in the highway?

Tags: word-request

I don't think we call it a wind, because it's not a wind if the air is hitting you, because the car is moving at a high speed. Is there a specific word for stagnant air (doesn't have to be stagnant since there can be a little wind in there too) that rushes into the car, because you are driving at a high speed?

Comment: on the highway, not in.

Comment: For boats and aircraft, where the distinction between 'air moving on its own' and 'vehicle moving relative to air' is important, this is called [apparent (vs true) wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_wind). For land vehicles the difference usually doesn't matter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In America, we call it wind.  For example, there are [song lyrics](https://www.bing.com/search?q=hotel%20california%20lyrics) about riding in a car (or maybe on a motorcycle) with the "wind in my hair."

This is also part of why the front glass on an American car or motorcycle is called a "[windshield](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/windshield)".

Comment: And In many parts of the world, that windshield is called windscreen. Even outside America *wind* should do.

Comment: If it's low velocity, we might call it a breeze; indeed, in French, a windshield is called pare-brise, "brise" being "breeze". But that's mincing; breeze is wind.